# DB migration on multiple Heroku Dynos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, meteor

I have a simple migration script for a `Meteor` app. On startup, it runs some code to modify all `Documents` in a `Collection`. I have 5 dynos running on Heroku and noticed in the logs that my `console.logs` got called 5x (1 per each dyno).

Does this mean that my `DB` is getting updated 5x too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/migrations to ensure that only one process can obtain the database lock at a time.

That way only one node will run the code for migrations.

Comment: I played around with that package for a while. I think it was overkill for what I need know because I'm not necessarily concerned with having versioning for this particular version change.

But would each web worker actually update the single DB?

Comment: what you need is locking. so if you don't want to use that package you could implement your own simple locking using a Mongo raw collection and `findOneAndUpdate()` to prevent race conditions.  That way only a single web worker would execute the migration.